# Error: While importing 'Flaskr.app', an ImportError was raised

Tags: python, flask

Im not even sure whats going on here.

I am trying to initialize my database within a flask app.

whenever I try to run init-db (which in my program is init-db2 because i made a second db file and deleted the first one) it

1. won't work saying that the command doesn't exist
2. provides this error for me "Error: While importing 'Flaskr.app', an ImportError was raised."

this doesn't make sense to me because I don't have a flaskr.py file, it is however the name of one of my directories for the app so I think there may be some confusion going on in the pathing?

my environment is set fine afaik

set FLASK_APP=app.py
set FLASK_ENV=development
python -m flask init-db2

my db2 file also is inline with the tutorial

```
    import sqlite3

import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext


def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db


def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db = get_db()

    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))

@click.command('init-db2')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    """Clear existing data and create new tables"""
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

and my init file also seems in accordance with the tutorial

```
    import os

from flask import Flask


def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    from . import db2
    db2.init_app(app)

    return app
```

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\ShoeManagementApp\Flaskr> set FLASK_APP=app.py
PS C:\Windows\System32\ShoeManagementApp\Flaskr> PS C:\Windows\System32\ShoeManagementApp\Flaskr> set FLASK_ENV=development
At line:1 char:1
+ PS C:\Windows\System32\ShoeManagementApp\Flaskr> set FLASK_ENV=develo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
 
PS C:\Windows\System32\ShoeManagementApp\Flaskr> PS C:\Windows\System32\ShoeManagementApp\Flaskr> python -m flask init-db2
At line:1 char:1
+ PS C:\Windows\System32\ShoeManagementApp\Flaskr> python -m flask init ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
 
PS C:\Windows\System32\ShoeManagementApp\Flaskr> Error: While importing 'Flaskr.app', an ImportError was raised.set FLASK_APP=app.py
At line:1 char:1
+ Error: While importing 'Flaskr.app', an ImportError was raised.set FL ...
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Error::String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

the only things I think could be causing this issue but don't know how to resolve are that I am using SQL alchemy from the earlier DB setup and now just sqlite as per the tutorial, I don't know if importing both will cause clashes.

Comment: Welcome to SO,. Please add the full error to your post (copy paste it, no screenshot)

Comment: thank you for pointing that out it's been added

Comment: Please add the full trace including the command you have issue.

Comment: I think i've gotten it in there now.

Comment: Well that's better, merge the previous and this one and we will have any we need. There is a problem in the way you invoke the command. Both PS and python complains. We need the FULL trace, execute it again, read it carefully once then post it from the very beginning including the command until the end of the error.

Comment: so, i think this is the entire path/error message. It seems to be having an issue with my dev environment? perhaps that's causing the issue? I could try porting it over to a linux VM and seeing what happens. I still have no idea where flaskr.py is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems you are executing the following command in PS:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\ShoeManagementApp\Flaskr> python -m flask init-db2
```

Which is probably a copy paste error, you are asking to exectute the prompt as well with the command. Just issue: `python -m flask init-db2` it should do the job!

Comment: i've been tweaking it in linux now for the past day and it's really strange to me that it gives me a import error for a file that I don't have in my code anywhere.                                                                                                         "Error: While importing 'flaskr.app', an ImportError was raised."

Comment: Well are you aware that my observations on my answer still apply? If the problem is also present on Linux, would you mind please add the information as well (command + error). Don't suppress the existing content, update with relevant information. We are not in front of your screen.

Comment: just wanted to update: so I figured out the error messages for the most part. The only issue left is that the program won't acknowledge the creation of the init-db command itself. trying to sort that out on my own. Secondarily, I think I realized what you mean about your observations yes. if I'm correct you were saying that i was not operating in the right working environment?